# $\tilde S$ is not always getting correctly rendered.

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I wrote $\tilde S$ in an answer it was rendered correctly, but when I wrote the same in a comment, it looked like just an $S$ with a horizontal bar over it, as if I had written $\bar S$.  And here on meta, it also looks like just a bar over an $S$.

Comment: Looks fine here. Let's try in a comment: $\tilde{S}$. Yup, also fine. Could be your browser, or the MathJax rendering engine you use. Which are you using?

Comment: Test: $\tilde S$, $\tilde{S}$, $\displaystyle\tilde S$, $\displaystyle\tilde{S}$ $\qquad$

Comment: Here on meta is looks correct in a comment but not in the posted question. $\qquad$

Comment: [This comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717385/variance-of-3-dimensional-vectors/1717403#comment3505495_1717403), I guess? Looks fine for me.

Comment: The $\tilde{S}$ in the body of your question is looking a little off to me, but it looks right in the title and the comments here. Also the comment that Daniel Fischer mentioned looks fine to me also.

Comment: I've seen this on numerous occasions (this post being one of them). In the end, I've blamed it on some zoom peculiarities. In this [zoomed-in snapshot](https://imgur.com/a6R8EGK) of this post (on 1920x1080) you can see that actually anti-aliasing is applied to make the "bar" in $\tilde S$ look *slightly* different from the one in $\bar S$. (Don't ask me how I noticed that slight AA difference.) Oh, and that is produced with HTML-CSS Fast Preview with STIX fonts installed on a Chrome clone/Win 7.

Comment: Don't use `\tilde` and `\bar`. Instead use `\widetilde` and `\overline`. Compare and contrast: $\tilde S\ \widetilde{S}$ and $\bar S\ \overline{S}$.

Comment: $\widetilde S$ $\qquad$

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu with chromium.

Comment: It appears that standard tilde $\tilde{X}$ versus wide tilde  $\widetilde{X}.$ And bar $\bar{R}$ versus overline $\overline{R}$ differ on Safari.